# There's a way to put % (sql) in java. Like this "select first_name from employees where first_name like 'A%e'"

Tags: java, sql

I want to find if a string contains something like "Are" ,or "Ate", or "Aste", or "Anche" so something like string.contains("A%e").
The java way to express:
select  first_name  from  employees  where  first_name  like  'A%e';
Thank you

Comment: You can test it either using a regular expression or a combination of `string.startsWith("A")` and `string.endsWith("e")`

Comment: Regex, I suppose.  Something like `"A.+e"` might work.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand. When you say "The java way to express", you could be ASKING "what is the java way to express ..." or you could be DECLARING "the java way to express is ..." (which it isn't; it's sql). I appreciate that english might not be your first language but please try to put more effort into asking questions in future; shorter isn't necessarily better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression. For example:

```
"Aste".matches("A.*e")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is possibile to do something like "("NelMezzDelCamminDiNostraVita".matches("N.*del.*ta")); = true?

Comment: Ok yes that thing that i wrote now on the comment return true, so thank you solved